# Oracle SQL to pick specific value in one column that consist of many values separated by commas

Tags: java, sql, oracle, grails

I have a table with 2 column name and package. One example value of package is "BGA,BGA DUAL DIE,QFP,QFP DUAL DIE".

[image]

How I can do a sql that it can pick exactly name of package I input.
Let say for my portion of code the input for bd.pkg is "BGA"

```
def generateBdHistoryTable(ApprovalHeader ah,BondingDiagram bd){
    if(bd.pkg!=null){
                String kitTypeHolder;
                def kitTypeMap = [:];
                List kitTypeLists = KitType.executeQuery("select name from KitType where (packages like '"+bd.pkg+"%' or packages like '%,"+bd.pkg+"%')");
```

The result was for rows that contains both

```
BGA  
BGA DUAL DIE
```

I only want name for package "BGA" to be result when the input is "BGA' and name of package"BGA DUAL DIE" when the input is so and etc. How I should do the query for case like this?

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and Oracle here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I had correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name
from   KitType
where  ','||packages||',' like '%,BGA,%'
```

Or using regular expressions:

```
select name
from   KitType
where  REGEXP_LIKE( packages, '(^|,)BGA(,|$)' )
```

Comment: When i tried it also call for name of package "BGA DUAL DIE" which value "BGA' doesn't have in it

Comment: @Memoc if you want exactly the string then I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **Like** clause you can use **CHARINDEX**. Try the following

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('BGA',ColumnName) >0)
```

It is for MySQL.
use INSTR for Oracle server

Comment: Sorry it is for MySQL. For ORACLE you can use INSTR

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select *
from yourTable
where regexp_instr(packages, '(^|\, )QFP(\,|$)') != 0
```

The conditions check for rows in which the input string ('BGA' in the example) exists and is followed by a comma or is at the end of the string and, as rightly suggested by MT0, is preceeded by ', ' or is at the beginning of the string

Comment: What about `XXBGA,ABC`? That will pass your test but does not contain exactly the `BGA` string.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle11g

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(PACKAGES,
                ',[^,]+,') PACKAGES
  FROM DUAL
) WHERE PACKAGES=INPUT;

In SQL Server

Create Below Function

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

```
    INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

END 
RETURN
```

END

select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString('Packages','') where splitdata=Input

Thanks